# blender geometry nodes increase angle along curve

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I want to to do a 3 fingers grip with Geometry Nodes.
Every finger is a curve composed of 4 vertex.

With a variable of the group input named 'Angle' I need to increase the natural angle of each couple of edges (alpha and beta).

[image]

I try the GN 'Set Curve Tilt' but I don't know how tell it the direction of the rotation.

My main Geometry Nodes

[image]

My Geometry Nodes 'GN finger'

[image]

Any idea how to do it?

[image]

Comment: you want to use a vector rotate and a set position, not a 'set curve tilt'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did it. My 3 fingers grip.

[image]

I show how I did it.

[image]

In the GN of the grip I positioned the three fingers.

[image]

In the GN 'finger' I created the three parts of each finger and I rotated them by the angle of desired of the hand. I rotated them a second time to orientated them correctly.

[image]

And finally in the GN 'Appearance' i created the cylinders of every finger and Uv spheres to linked them.

Answer (score 3):

For an unknown number of points, you could use a setup like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since I was recently urged to give more upvotes: Well done, this answer is very helpful! ;-)